# Need help to remove default Windows 10 apps via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to debloat Windows 10 Education by running the following commands in a powershell script. I can get the script to remove the apps for the logged in user but as soon as someone new logs in, the apps reappear.

Here is my script:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*3DBuilder*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*windowsalarms*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*windowscamera*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*windowscommunicationsapps*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*officehub*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*getstarted*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*windowsmap*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*solitairecollection*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*bingfinance*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*bingnews*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*zunevideo*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*people*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*windowsphone*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*bingsports*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*windowsstore*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*soundrecorder*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*bingweather*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*xboxapp*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*Appconnector*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*MinecraftUWP*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*Messaging*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*WindowsFeedbackHub*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*Getstarted*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*GetHelp*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*ContactSupport*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*Wallet*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*OneConnect*”} | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you need to use the -Online parameter

```
$Apps = Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
$Apps | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*windowscommun*"} | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf I will try this version too.

Comment: This answer is correct because of the difference between `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage` and `Get-AppxPackage`. AppxPackage get packages that are already installed, AppxProvisionedPackage gets packages in the repository. If it's a freshly image before anyone logs in then you can just use AppxProvisionedPackage, but if users have logged in both will need to be used.

Answer (score -1):

You've got the `-AllUsers` switch set on `Get-AppxPackage`, but not on `Remove-AppxPackage`. If you do add it to the end of each line, you should get the expected behavior. Note that I don't think you need the first AllUsers switch, but it can't hurt to keep it in (excluding that it'll probably make the commands take longer to complete.)

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –like “*3DBuilder*”} | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

Comment: There is no -AllUsers paramter with Remove-AppxPackage

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i will try adding that to my script now :)

Comment: @OlafReitz it didn't in Windows 8, but it certainly does in Windows 10: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/appx/remove-appxpackage